# uint[] to address with correct checksum

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.5.x

Lets say we have something like this as a given:

```
bytes20 b = bytes20(someAddress);
uint8[] memory array = new uint8[](b.length);
for (uint256 n = 0; n < b.length; n++) {
  array[n] = uint8(uint160(b) / (2 ** (8 * (19 - n))));
}
```

After performing operations on the `array` (which would change the casing) I would like to bring it back to an address with the correct checksum, without converting it to a string with a proper casing, and then the string to address. In other words, I am looking for a clean solution. Solidity version is 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable of type `address` in the EVM is stored as raw bytes so they do not have case.

For an addres to have case it only make sense when the address is stored as hexadecimal string.

Usually it is responsibility of the library/framework you are using.